# ionic + Android 9 + File Transfer

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

i am facing the issue with ionic4 file transfer,
file transfer is not working with **android 9**, 
i have tested below **android 9** it is working fine.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install @ionic-native/file-transfer
```

**MY CODE IS**

```
uploadImageFile() {
var options: FileUploadOptions = {
  fileKey: "userPhoto",
  mimeType: "image/jpeg",
  chunkedMode: false,
}

this.URL = 'http://webservicelink.in:1224/mobile/upload';

this.FileUpload.upload(this.imageURI, this.URL, options)
  .then((data) => {
   alert("Success uploading image");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    alert("Error uploading image");
  });
}
```

**ERROR**

{"code":3"source":"file///stoRAGE/EMULATED/0/xENDER/PHOTO/20190704-wa003.jpeg","target":"http://webservicelink.in:1224/mobile/upload","http_status":null,"body":null,"Exception":"Write error: ssl0x7cf2dd3f88:I/O error during system call,Broken pipe"}

Answer (score 1):

**Filetransfer is Depricated**

> https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer
>
> Deprecated With
>   the new features introduced in XMLHttpRequest, this plugin is not
>   needed any more. Migrating from this plugin to using the new features
>   of XMLHttpRequest, is explained in this Cordova blog post.